# StoreKit: can I offer a user a free download for a product of his choice that normally costs?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storekit

I'll soon have to implement the StoreKit functionality and I was wondering...
is there a way to also offer a product for free to a user once, like as a gift for using the app for the first time ?

In my special scenario I'll offer several products in my educational app, which the user will need to buy time by time, if he is interested in continuing to learn with the app.
But the first product I want the user to have for free and it should be his choice which one he takes. So generally all products should have a price, but the first download shall be free.
And I want this to get logged on my server so I can reidentify him, so (A) he can't delete the app, reinstall and download yet another free product and (B) so he will also get the products on any other of his devices.

I'm also open to workarounds, like maybe get something similar to the apple id or so, to be able to store it on the server. I know that I could also use the [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], but I want the user to have this first free product on all his devices, and ONLY ONE.

Is there a way to get (A) and (B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's In-App Purchase infrastructure (and by extension, StoreKit) does not support free content.

But there's nothing stopping you from providing free content via your own mechanisms, as you surmise. You would have to do all the tracking yourself in terms of remembering device IDs on a server somewhere, and noting that device != user, so would miss some edge cases.

You don't get access to (iTunes) user data at all, so you probably can't guarantee the "only once" across multiple devices, unless your app has an associated backend service account that is already unique per user.

(Before building infrastructure for this, you should double-check the developer agreement/contracts on this stuff. You're not circumventing Apple's revenue stream here, which is good, but what you're talking about may be unusual enough to raise a flag with them in terms of experience consistency if nothing else.)

Comment: Not what I wanted to here, but I guess you can't have everything :D And thanks for the reminder to look into the agreement.